# Wamp2 x86 PHP 5.4 TS - sqlsrv module not loading

Tags: php, sql-server, php-extension, sqlsrv

I see that many people had issues like that, however I could not find solution that would just work.

My phpinfo() says:

```
PHP Version 5.4.16
Server API Apache 2.0 Handler
Thread Safety   enabled
```

I've downloaded: http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/
readme says that if I have PHP 5.4 TS I should load those files:

```
php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

I've loaded above, but only PDO extension seems to work fine:

```
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, sqlsrv
pdo_sqlsrv support  enabled
```

However I can not see sqlsrv extensions anywhere.
I've checked PHP error.log and it's also empty.

Do you have idea why those MS libs does not work and how can I debug it?

I've small project on Windows and configuring ones stack seems to be pretty hard comparing to Linux.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: I was doing some cleanups, but fair enough, if you find this post worthwhile I've undeleted it.